# Why Fragment's menu items dismiss, get mixed, replace other items after Fragment is shown/hidden?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

**The problem description**

I have `BaseFragment` that is responsible for showing back buttons, handling back button clicks, setting toolbar as action bar. All of my fragments extend from it. Couple of them has menu items. I don't use fragment replacing, I use only add/show/hide. So, when my fragment appears, their menu items can disappear, also can be replaced by other's fragment's menu items or sometimes can get mixed. Here is my `BaseFragment`:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

abstract fun getToolbar(): Toolbar?


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(getToolbar())
}

//this function is called when fragment needs to show back button
fun showBackButtonOnFragment() {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}

//handling onBackPressed 
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if (item?.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
        activity?.onBackPressed()
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Here is one of my child fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` method. Note that I don't call `setHasOptionsMenu()`, cause it's called in `BaseFragment`.

```
public class HistoryFragment extends BaseFragment  {

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //here I don't use super to call base method
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@Nullable MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.filter_menu:
            openFilterActivity();
    }
    return true;
}



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Toolbar getToolbar() {
        return this.toolbar;
    }
  }
```

**What I tried**

I tried to call `menu.clear()` in `BaseFragment` to remove all menu items if they somehow still left. It didn't work. I suspect that calling `setHasOptionsMenu()` in `BaseFragment` could be bad idea, cause some fragment does not have menu items at all. For that, I created abstract function to identify, does child fragment need menu and according to result, I called `setHasOptionsMenu()` with true or false. But it didn't help.

**Question**
What can be the reason for the problem? Is my `BaseFragment` guilty for that? How the problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `setHasOptionsMenu()` calls `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. I highly suspect that.

You should call `setHasOptionsMenu()` manually in sub fragments, while not calling it in your `BaseFragment`.

Comment: Thanks for response, but didn't help. I use BottomNavigationView and when I select first tab, after second tab, after that I open another fragment(let's call it 'child') from first tab. And when I return to second tab, its menu item is replaced with menu item of 'child' fragment.

Comment: Oh, so it keeps the previous' menu? Then you should invalidate the Fragment's options menu everytime it resumes on `onResume()`. It happens that I believe you invalidate (=change) the menu only on creation, not when it resumes.

Comment: In order to use invalidateOptionsMenu in Fragment, do I need to use getActivity method?

Comment: Yes, `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`. At least that was my idea.

Comment: If I am not wrong, `invalidateOptionsMenu` triggers `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Is your idea is to handle this method and configure menus? But if menu item is not simple, I mean, if it is `SearchView`, so is it possible?

Comment: My idea is that your child `Fragment` is updating the menu and upon `onBackPressed()` the menu stays the child's, because the parent needs to refresh the menu. Just try to refresh the menu in the `onResume()` of your fragments.